# A star pathfinding. Why do you need to re-evaluate an adjacent node that's already in the open list if it has a lower g cost to the current node?

Tags: algorithm, a-star

There is one thing about a star path finding algorithm that I do not understand. In the pseudocode; if the current node's (the node being analysed) g cost is less than the adjacent nodes g cost then recalculate the adjacent nodes g,h a f cost and reassign the parent node. 
Why do you do this?

Why do you need to reevaluate the adjacent nodes costs and parent if it's gCost is greater than the current nodes gCost? I'm what instance would you need to do this?

Edit; I am watcing this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0qCR18gXdU\

At at 8.19 he says: When you come across blocks (nodes) that have already been analysed, the question is should we change the properties of the block?

Comment: Hi i'm watching a tutorial that doesn't give any pseudo code or I would paste it in my question. Instead I've linked the video and a quote for the thing he says that I don't understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This guy is totally wrong because he says change the parent node however your succesors are based on your parent node and if you change parent Node then you you can't have a valid path because the path is simply by moving from parent to child.

Instead of changing parent, Pathmax function. It says that if  a parent Node **A** have a child node whose cost (heuristic(A) <= heuristic(A) + accumulated(cost)) then set the cost of child equal to the cost of parent.

**PathMax to ensure monotonicty:**

**Monotonicity:** Every parent Node has cost greater or equal then the cost of it's child node.

**A* has a property:** It says that if your cost is monotonically increasing then the **first** (sub)path that A* finds is always the part of the final path.   More precisely: Under monotonicity each node is reach first through the best path.

Do you see why?

Suppose you have a graph :(A,B) (B,C) (A,E) ,(E,D) here every tuple means they are connected. Suppose cost is monotonically increasing and your algortihm chooses (A,B),(B,C) and at this point you know your algorithm have chosen best path till now and everyother path which can reach this node,must have cost higher but if the cost is not monotonically increasing then it can be the case that (A,E) is cost greater than your current cost and from (E,D) it's zero. so you have better path there.

This algorithm relies on it's heuristic function , if it's underustimated then it gets corrected by accumulated cost but if it's over-estimated then it can explore extra node and i leave it for you why this happends.

**Why do you need to re-evaluate an adjacent node that's already in the open list if it has a lower g cost to the current node?**

Don't do this because it's just extra work.

Corollary: if you later come the same node from a node p with same cost then simply  remove that node from queue. Do not extend it.

Answer (score 0):

First a tip.  You can actually add the time you want as a bookmark to get a video that starts right where you want.  In this case https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0qCR18gXdU#t=08m19s is the bookmarked time link.

Now the quick answer to your question.  We fill in a node the first time we find a path to it.  But the first path we found to it might not be the cheapest one.  We want the cheapest one, and if we find a cheaper one second, we want it.

Here is a visual metaphor.  Imagine a running path with a fence next to it.  The spot we want is on the other side of the fence.  Actually draw this out, it will help.

The first path that our algorithm finds to it is run down the path, jump over the fence.  The second path that we find is run part way down the path, go through the gate, then get to that spot.  We don't want to throw away the idea of using the gate just because we already figured out that we could get there by jumping the fence!

Now in your picture put costs of moving from one spot to another that are reasonable for moving along a running path, an open field, through a gate, and jumping a fence.  Run the algorithm by hand and you'll see that you figure out first that you can jump the fence, and then later that you really wanted to use the gate.